# Google CSE custom search CSS

Tags: css, google-custom-search

Ok, I am usually very good with CSS but this has me completely perplexed. I have used a css detector tool on my google custom search bar to try to spot the problem but to no avail. This is the website (you can see the search bar in the header top-right):

http://www.goldtokens.net/

The "google custom search" bit of text seems vertically displaced from the text box. I can't seem to find any css reason why. The margins and paddings of all elements (that I can see) seem to be fine.

Comment: I am ok Praveen but bit frustrated lol

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  Combining `google`, `custom` and `search` does not mean you're talking about Google Custom Search, which has its own tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css in your `main.css` file causing problem:

```
table {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 10px auto 30px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Remove margin and it sorts itself out :)